# GroupBy after SelectMany in EF causes SQL error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to query Device object from the DB with some additional statistics.

Devices have associated Images (`ImageMetadatas`) and each `ImageMetadatas` may have some tags.

The goal is to get number of images and number of tags for each returned device.

Here's the my query, that fails with an error `SqlState: 42803`:

> ERROR: column "i0.ImageId" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Code:

```
var result = await this.Devices
                       .Include(d => d.DeviceType)
                       .AsExpandable()
                       .Where(criteria) // Filtering on devices
                       .Select(d => new
                                    {
                                        Device = d, // device object
                                        CountOfImages = d.ImageMetadatas.Count(), // count of images associated to the device
                                        Tags = d.ImageMetadatas // get Tag statistics
                                                .SelectMany(im => im.Tags)
                                                .Where(tagsFilter.Compile()) // some filters on tags
                                                .Select(t => t.Name)
                                                .GroupBy(t => t)
                                                .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }),
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: ` .GroupBy(t => t)` ? How could this be translated to SQL? The only way would be to put all properties in the `GROUP BY` clause. Use g`GroupBy(t=>t.Name)` instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .GroupBy(t => t) translated to sql as "GROUP BY t."Name"", I tried to remove .Select(t => t.Name) and use GroupBy(t=>t.Name) - same result

Comment: Looks like a bug. Not sure that this is fixed in EF Core 6 also. There is no need to use  `ImageId` for eager loading query.